# Can I Use Xdebug on a Remote Server with Multiple Developers where Requests Come from a Proxy Server?

Tags: php, debugging, configuration, proxy, xdebug

Here is my situation:

- Our company has a central web server, *R*, for testing our PHP
  applications on.
- I develop on my local machine, *L*, and upload to *R*
  for testing.
- Our apps run in such a way that a client running on *L*
  makes requests to a proxy server *P*; *P* then forwards the request to *R*
  and processes the response. The processed response is sent back from
  *P* to the client on *L*.

Essentially I want to know if there is a way of informing Xdebug running on *R* that a debug session should be started up with *L* when the requests originate from *P*.

I can't hard-code in the IP of *L* in Xdebug's config because there could be other developers connecting.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DBG PHP Debugger](http://php-debugger.com) and have a statement in your php file like so. Note that the author of the debugger has an [IDE](http://nusphere.com/products/php_debugger.htm) as well.

This statement will forward debug info to the IP address that is running a debug client. We restrict it running to the same IP that hit the URL.

```
if($IP == '192.168.x.x')
{
    DebugBreak('192.168.x.x');
}
```